# open a bootstrap modal single time when page load in codeigniter website?

Tags: php, codeigniter, bootstrap-modal, pageload, page-refresh

I want to open a bootstrap modal on page load. but my problem is that at every page refresh, it do gets launch but I want to display it only single time when user redirect on the that page.

Can anyone suggest me how to do that?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Adding $('#myModal').modal(options) to a document ready function in Javascript will call the modal on window load. [Via javascript](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/modal/#via-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

Yes there are many ways to do that... You can send $_GET parameter in url Something like this:-

```
Suppose Url :- localhost/modal?open=modal
```

Now in Jquery You can do like this:-

```
<script> //not forget to add ready function
 <?php if(isset($_GET['open'])  && $_GET['open']=="modal"){ ?>
  $("#somemodalid").modal('show') //open modal here
 <?php } ?>
 </script>
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Can it be possible in this way while on a page load?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(window).on('load',function(){
        $('#myModal').modal('show');
    });
</script>
```

Hoping that you have used bootstrap modal box as you haven't mentioned the code so.

Comment: wrong answer totally they want to open modal at particular route

Comment: Same problem , it will launch modal at each page load, I want only single time.

Comment: You want something like to open it once uniquely right?

Comment: @ManeeshSharma see my answer

Comment: only thing you can do is to store ip in cookies and check everytime request comes up.....